# node.js + socket.io authetificate right away

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to run authentification as soon as socket is connected?
Right now I do this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('login', function (token) {
    // this is where I currently authtificate users
    });
});
```

If I'm not wrong in this case socket opens on "connection" and hangs there and "login" event may be never called. If someone wants to attack my server, they can simply open thousands of socket connections. How can I authentificate on "connection", I mean right away? So if it fails I will be able to close socket immediately.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean authentificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run authentication when a client tries to connect. Socket.io has a mechanism of authorizing clients when they try to connect to your server, However **authorization** is disabled by default. There is an object of `handshake` when a socket tries to connect to server, this object has the request query and request headers etc. You can enforce authorization by this:

```
io.configure(function (){
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
  if(handshakeData.query.token == "somevalue"){
    callback(null, true); // this will allow the client to connect
    }else{
    callback(null, false); // this will prevent the client from connecting
    } 
  });
});
```

And on the client side you can send a query string like this:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://yourIP:Port?token=somevalue");
```